# wordpress pagination after changing permalink structure to postname

Tags: php, wordpress

After changing to any permalink structure, I get "Page not found" whenever I change pages on my blog. Here's my code:

```
<div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
            <?php
                global $paged;
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args = array (
                    'post_type' => 'blog',
                    'status' => 'published',
                    'posts_per_page' => 4,
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'orderby' => 'desc',
                    );
                $blogPosts = new WP_Query($args);

                while($blogPosts->have_posts()): $blogPosts->the_post(); ?>
                    <div id="blog-post-<?php echo the_ID(); ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <div id="blog-header">
                                <h5><?php echo the_title(); ?></h5>
                                <strong>-<?php echo the_author(); ?></strong>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div id="blog-content">
                            <p id="content-<?php echo the_ID(); ?>">
                                <?php echo the_content(); ?>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            <!-- **Pagination** -->
            <div class="pagination">
            <?
                $next = get_next_posts_link('<span>Older Posts</span>', $blogPosts->max_num_pages);
                $prev = get_previous_posts_link('<span>Newer Posts</span>');
            ?>
                <div class="prev-post">                     
                    <?php echo $prev; ?> 
                </div>           
                <div class="next-post"> 
                    <?php echo $next;?>                 
                </div>enter code here
            </div><!-- **Pagination - End** --> 
        </div><!-- #content -->
```

I need this to work to any name permalink structure. Thanks in advance!

Comment: By 'change pages' do you mean via the menu, or older/newer?

Comment: Older. I made it to display the new ones first

Comment: Wordpress has a codex page on Permalinks, there are a few things there it recommends doing http://codex.wordpress.org/Permalinks. Have you checked your .htaccess file has updated properly?